# Create Random points

Tags: arcgis-desktop, point

I have polygon with an attribute which has numbers populated in it. I would like to create random points for each of the polygon depending on the attribute. How could this be done ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the [Create Random Points](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000002r000000) tool does exactly what you want. It requires either an Advanced license, a 3D Analyst or Spatial Analyst extension.